# A Function in an application(.exe) should be called only once regardless of how many times I run the same application

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Suppose there are two functions, one to print "hello" and other to print "world" and I call these two functions inside the main function. Now, when I compile it will create a .exe file. When I run this .exe for the **first time** both functions will print "hello world".This .exe is terminated.

But if I run the same .exe for the **second time or multiple times**, only one function must execute ie. it should print only "world". I want to a piece of code or function that should only run once and after that, it should destroy itself and should be not be executed again regardless of how many times I run the application(.exe)

I can achieve this by accessing locally or windows registry and write some value for once and can check if that value is present, no need to execute this piece of code or function.

Can I achieve it without any external help that the application itself should be capable of performing this behaviour?
Any ideas are appreciated. thanks for reading

Comment: The only way you could do this is if you modified the executable to set a value.  Such a construct is very system specific and most likely fragile.  You're better off storing status in an external file.

Comment: You'd need to store some state somewhere - like in a file or database or whatever - that your program checks, to see if it has already been run once. Otherwise, every execution of the program will have *no* knowledge of any previous executions of the program. A program has no "memory" of previous runs unless you specifically write code to create and check such persistent memory.

Comment: Why would you want to write a self-destroying program?

Comment: @KevinBoone Well, my application when update, my ApplicationUpgrader.exe deletes some files for the first time. Then during the second update, I don't want  ApplicationUpgrader.exe to delete these files. My only solution is to write values in the registry during the first update & check that value exists in the second update. Well, I want to avoid these steps and write a one-time code for it in the first update itself.

Comment: I would think that a neater solution than having the program modify itself would be to equip it with enough logic to work out what steps it needs to carry out, each time it is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I achieve it without any external help that the application itself
> should be capable of performing this behaviour?

Not by any means defined by C or C++, and probably not on Windows at all.

You have to somehow, somewhere memorialize the fact that the one-time function has been called.  If you have nothing but the compiled program to use for that, then the only alternative is to modify the program.  Neither C nor C++ provides for live modification of the running program, much less for writing it back to the executable file containing its image.

Conceivably, if the program knows where to find or how to recreate its own source code, and if it knows how to run the compiler, then it could compile a modified version of itself.  On Windows, however, it very likely could not overwrite its own executable file while it was running (though that would be possible on various other operating systems), so that would not solve the problem.

Moreover, note that any approach that involves modifying the executable would be at least a bit wonky, for different copies of the program would have their own, semi-independent idea of whether the one-time function had been run.

Basically, then, no.

Answer (score 2):

There is no coherent or portable way<sup>1</sup> to do this from software without requiring the use of an external resource of some kind.

The issue is that you want the invocation of this process to be aware of the amount of times it has been executed, but the amount of times it has been executed is not a property that is recorded anywhere<sup>2</sup>. A program itself has no memory of its previous executions unless you program it do so.

Your best bet is to write out this information in some canonicalized location so that it can be read on later executions. This could be as a file in the filesystem (such as a hidden `.firstrun` file or something), or it could be through the registry (Windows specific), or some other environment-specific form of communication.

The main thing is that this must persist between executions and be available to your process.

---

<sup>1</sup> You *could* potentially write code that overwrites the executable itself after the first invocation -- but this is extraordinarily brittle, and will be highly specific to the executable format. This is not an ideal nor recommended approach to solving this problem.

<sup>2</sup> This is not a capability defined in the C or C++ standard. It's possible that there may be some specialized operating systems/flavors of linux that allow querying this -- but this is not something seen in most general-purpose operating systems. Generally the approach is communicate via an external resource.